# How to export IB position data to a data frame?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I was trying to export IB position/account value into data frame for further processing purposes in python.  But failed to figure out how to achieve this.  Can anyone help?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import time 

import ibapi
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
import threading
import sys
import queue

from ibapi.contract import Contract

class MyWrapper(EWrapper):
#@property        
    def updatePortfolio(self, contract: Contract, position: float, marketPrice: float, marketValue: float, averageCost: float, unrealizedPNL: float, realizedPNL: float, accountName: str):
        super().updatePortfolio(contract, position, marketPrice, marketValue, averageCost, unrealizedPNL, realizedPNL, accountName)
        if (len(contract.symbol)<5) & (contract.secType == 'STK'):
            new_symbol = contract.symbol.zfill(5)
        else:
            new_symbol = contract.symbol
        print (contract.secType, contract.exchange, new_symbol, "Position:", position, "MarketPrice:", marketPrice, "MarketValue:", marketValue, "AverageCost:", averageCost, "UnrealizedPNL:", unrealizedPNL, "RealizedPNL:", realizedPNL)

accountName = '' 
callback = MyWrapper() # wrapper = MyWrapper()
#Instntiate My Wrapper.callback
tws = EClient(callback) # app = EClient(wrapper)
  #Instantiate EClient and return data to call back
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 4001
clientID = 8
tws.connect(host, port, clientID)                 

print("serverVersion:%s connectionTime:%s" %     (tws.serverVersion(), tws.twsConnectionTime()))
print(tws.isConnected())

    tws.reqAccountUpdates(1, accountName)
time.sleep(2)
tws.run()
accvalue = pd.DataFrame(callback.updatePortfolio, columns = ['Symbol','Position','MarketPrice','MarketValue',
                            'AverageCost', 'UnrealisedPnL', 'RealisedPnL'])
#accvalue = callback.updateAccountValue
print ('Account: \n' + accvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You need to set up the queue class objects inside of the wrapper to collect the response from the client function you are calling. Then, you can do anything you want with the data. Take a look at this blog --> https://qoppac.blogspot.com/2017/03/interactive-brokers-native-python-api.html

There is some code there you can reuse to help with the implementation.